# How can I know it a tire bubble is caused by a "road hazzard?"

Tags: tires, wheels

I bought new tires for my car (2015 Audi A3) a little less than 3 years ago. But due to some medical issues I wasn't able to drive for a while, on and off, so the tires have maybe 10,000 miles maximum on them. They're basically new tires (Hankooks). The front driver's side tire already has a bubble in it.

Anyway, I called Hankook and they told me I need to bring it to an "authorized Hankook distributor" to have them tell if it's caused by a road hazzard or not and then they'd have to file the warranty claim.

Something in my gut tells me they're just going to say it was caused by a road hazzard by default; they probably don't want to go through the process of filing a warranty claim and they just want their money. Unfortunately the only Hankook distributor near me doesn't have the greatest reputation, they're pretty sleazy. So nothing would surprise me with them.

Normally I buy my tires online, I'd never buy from them. But if it's the only shot I have at getting it covered with some warranty, I guess I have no choice. I'd at least like to go into the shop with some backbone before they tell me it's not covered.

Comment: Questions about tire health are off topic on this site because they often have subjective answers, and this one isn't different. You won't be able to do this yourself as you'd have to take the tire off the rim.